# Intial Output disappears when I change the enter some data in another field

Tags: reactjs, parent-child, custom-component

This is `App.js` file as parent component

```
import InputForm from "./Componets/input_child";
import OutputForm from "./Componets/output_child";
import React from "react";
function App() {
  const [data, ChangeData] = React.useState('')

  function getData(inputs)
  {
    ChangeData(inputs);
  }

  return (
    <div >
      <InputForm onChange = {getData}></InputForm>
      <OutputForm output = {data}></OutputForm>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is is `input_child.js` as child componet of `App.js`

```
function InputForm(props)
{
    const userinput = {};

    function getName(event)
    {
        userinput.name = event.target.value;
        props.onChange(userinput);
    }

    function getNumber(event)
    {
        userinput.number = event.target.value;
        props.onChange(userinput);
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <form>
                <div>
                    <label>Name: </label>
                    <input type='text' onChange={getName}></input>
                </div>
                
                <div>
                    <label>Number: </label>
                    <input type='text' onChange={getNumber}></input>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    );

}
export default InputForm;
```

This is `output_child.js` as another child component of `App.js`

```
function OutputForm(props)
{

    return(
        <div>
            <div>
               {props.output.name}
            </div>
            <div>
            {props.output.number}
            </div>
        </div>
    );

}
export default OutputForm;
```

When I enter something in name field, it appears as output. But disappears if I enter something in number filed. I want to display the content of Name field even if I enter something in number field.
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

you are passing object from your InputForm component as per your following code

```
const userinput = {};
 function getName(event)
    {
        userinput.name = event.target.value;
        props.onChange(userinput);
    }

    function getNumber(event)
    {
        userinput.number = event.target.value;
        props.onChange(userinput);
    }
```

So that in App.js also you should handle state as object as following

```
const [data, ChangeData] = React.useState('')
function getData(inputs)
  {
    ChangeData({...data, ...inputs});
  }
```

I hope this will solve your problem

Comment: @Roshan Ojha , Please Accept the answer if it solve your problem